# Unable to install/activate MATE desktop after lxde

Tags: 18.04, mate, lxde

I am doing proposed installation steps for mate desktop, and no error messages occur. But Mate desktop doesn't activate, I am still logging in into lxde.

How to switch to Mate?

Comment: Did you choose MATE as your wanted desktop at login? (ie. greeter screen where you enter your username & password)

Comment: `lxde` doesn't suggest any choice. I was to uninstall `lubuntu*` packages to wipe out `lxde`.

Comment: Your system may have been set on *last used*, or had *LXDE* as the default.. either way at the greeter you select the desktop you use for that session.  My system has three DEs installed (lubuntu (LXQt), ubuntu (thus GNOME) & xubuntu (XFCE)) and I select at login. You weren't specific on what you installed (LXDE to me implies other than Lubuntu), nor what your base system was (thus what DM you're using), but Lubuntu will include OpenBox & Lubuntu options at login for 18.04/bionic systems.

Comment: @guiverc my greeter didn't allow me to choose desktop

Comment: You haven't told me what greeter you are using (it's usually performed by your DM, be it `lightdm`, `gdm3`, or other)  Each DM has a different way of changing the DE you login, and it can be missed if you're not aware of the option (on some it's obvious, but others are not as it's an option most users will never use).